# Is there an equivalent to SQL's EXPLAIN in R?

Tags: r

I have a function and I'm going to make it an api end point with `plumber`. I'd like to get a sense for how long the function will take to run and which parts are eating up the most time.

I can get a general sense by looking at each of the parts of the function and guessing for how demanding a computation it is -- and I've done that to get through the first part.

Is there a command that will lay out the execution path and the estimated demand, like [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-explain/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`profvis::profvis`](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/).